# How to change language without a href?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, multilingual

I build a localization but I do not want to use a href to change language like

```
<a href="/{{language.code}}/"><button class="button">{{language.label}}</button></a>
```

I would like to do it by click without changing the URL like

```
<button class="button" (click)="changeLanguage(language.code)">{{language.label}}</button>

changeLanguage(lang){
    this.localeId=lang;
  }
```

How to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `navigate` method from the `Router` class

```
constructor(){
private router:Router
}

changeLanguage(lang){
  this.router.navigate(['/'+lang])
}
```

check official [**`doc`**](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: I don't want to do routing at all. Is it possible to get rid of navigation and just to change language?